# Estimation using mlogit in R

Tags: r, estimation, mlogit

I have a paper where the author proposes a D-optimal design for Nested Multinomial Logit Model with No-Choice. The design is as follows:

**CS 1:**

*Alt A:* 1  2   2   1   2   2

*Alt B:* 2  2   1   2   1   2

*Alt C:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

**CS 2:**

*Alt 1:* 2  1   1   2   2   2

*Alt 2:* 2  2   2   2   1   1

*Alt 3:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

**CS 3:**

*Alt 1:* 2  2   1   1   1   2

*Alt 2:* 1  1   2   2   2   1

*Alt 3:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

**CS 4:**

*Alt 1:* 2  2   1   1   2   1

*Alt 2:* 1  1   2   2   1   2

*Alt 3:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

**CS 5:**

*Alt 1:* 1  2   1   2   2   1

*Alt 2:* 2  1   2   1   1   2

*Alt 3:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

**CS 6:**

*Alt 1:* 1  2   1   2   1   2

*Alt 2:* 2  1   2   1   2   1

*Alt 3:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

**CS 7:**

*Alt 1:* 2  1   1   2   2   1

*Alt 2:* 1  2   2   1   2   2

*Alt 3:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

**CS 8:**

*Alt 1:* 2  1   2   2   2   1

*Alt 2:* 1  2   2   1   1   2

*Alt 3:* 0  0   0   0   0   0

The design is a D-optimal design with 8 Choice Sets and every choice set has 2 alternatives (6 two-level attributes by alternative). I tried to estimate the Nested Multinomial Logit Model in R using mlogit and that design. Thus, I made a simulated data using a random response as follow:

**Individual--Choiceid--Mode----Choice----AA--AB--AC--AD--AE--AF**
------1-------------1----------A-------FALSE-----1-----2-----2-----1-----2-----2
------1-------------1----------B-------FALSE-----2-----2-----1-----2-----1-----2
------1-------------1----------C--------TRUE-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0
------1-------------2----------A-------FALSE-----2-----1-----1-----2-----2-----2
------1-------------2----------B--------TRUE-----2-----2-----2-----2-----1-----1
------1-------------2----------C-------FALSE-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0-----0
------1-------------3----------A-------FALSE-----2-----2-----1-----1-----1-----2
------1-------------3----------B-------FALSE-----1-----1-----2-----2-----2-----1

The data contains responses of 30 people, that means, the data contains 240 choices (8 choices by person). However when I used the command

```
sim = read.csv("sim.csv",header=T)  
dat <- mlogit.data(sim, choice = "choice", shape = "long",
                          alt.var = "mode", chid.var = "choideid",id.var="individual")
nl.dat <- mlogit(choice ~ AA+AB+AC+AD+AE, dat, reflevel="C",
                       nests = list(OUR = c("A","B") , SQ = c("C")),
                       unscaled = TRUE)
```

I get the following error

> Error in solve.default(crossprod(attr(x, "gradi")[, !fixed])) :
>   system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number =
>   1.13304e-18

Someone has idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "Someone has idea what I'm doing wrong?" - system is computationally singular. Can't be solved.

Comment: Add more cases (simulations).

Comment: I made simulation with 5600 choices, and i got the same error. I computed a simulation with a numerical variables and i got the same error "sometime". For obtain numerical variables i took a rule:

If level=3 then rand(75,100)
if level=2 then rand(50,75)
if level=1 then rand(0,50)

But using only factor variables I compute over and over simulated responses and i got the same error.